# How to fix AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'config' in pytest module

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

Problem:- I am unable to load the pytest.config object in my test cases. It is showing that config is not an object in pytest module (At compile time itself).

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'config'
```

There are certain configuration parameters available in pytest.config object (Which are written in Utility scripts) which needs to be consumed by different test cases.

Background:- We are basically migrating old test framework to the new test framework. In this migration project, we have to consume plugin objects set to the pytest.config object (I am new to pytest framework).

```
 search = pytest.config.deployment_object
```

I am unable to get the deployment_object from pytest.config object

Comment: What are `Utility scripts` ? are you talking about a custom pytest module ?

Comment: Yes. Utility scripts(list of pytest plugins) are created by some other team. I don't have permissions to modify them.

Comment: Please provide an example of the parameters you would like to load